# Edit a XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, edit, filewriter

I have the following XML file:

```
<Tables>
    <table>
        <row></row>
    </table>
<Tables>
```

and I want to edit it to :

```
<Tables>
    <table>
        <row>some value</row>
    </table>
<Tables>
```

I write the XML file using file writer. How can I edit it?

What I was found that I create a temp file contains edits then delete the original file and rename the temp file. Is there any other way?

that's my code to write the file:

```
public boolean createTable(String path, String name, String[] properties) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
    writer.write("<Tables>");
    writer.write("\t<" + name + ">");
    for(int i=0; i<properties.length; i++){
        writer.write("\t\t<" + properties[0] + "></" + properties[0] + ">");
    }
    writer.write("\t</" + name + ">");
    writer.write("</Tables>");
    writer.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I see no Java here. Are you trying to write to an XML file using Java? Show some code.

Comment: Add your java codes to the question.

Comment: @Tdorno i put my code

Comment: @PreshanPradeepa i put my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your xml is static you can use this, here input.xml is your xml file

```
File file = new File("input.xml");
byte[] data;
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
   data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(data);
}
String input = new String(data, "UTF-8");
String tag = "<row>";
String newXML = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length()) + "your value" + input.substring(input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(), input.length());
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file)) {
    fw.write(newXML);
}
System.out.println("XML Updated");
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't read and write XML yourself. Java comes with multiple API's for parsing and generating XML, which takes care of all the encoding and escaping issues for you:

- `DOM` XML is loaded into memory in a tree structure.
- `SAX` XML is processed as a sequence of events. This is a push-parser, where the parser calls your code for each event.
- `StAX` XML is read as a sequence of events/tokens. This is a pull-parser, where your code calls the parser to get next value.

You can also find many third-party libraries for parsing XML, and Java itself also supports marshalling of XML to POJO's.

In your case I'd suggest DOM, since it's easiest to use. Don't use DOM for huge XML files, since it loads the entire file into memory. For huge files, I'd suggest StAX.

Other than encoding issues, using an XML parser will make the code less susceptible to minor variations in the input, e.g. the 3 empty `row` elements below all mean the same. Or is the `row` element even empty, and how to get rid of existing content like shown:

```xml
<!-- row is empty -->
<row></row>
<row/>
<row />

<!-- row has content -->
<row>5 + 7 &lt; 10</row>
<row><![CDATA[5 + 7 < 10]]></row>
<row><condition expr="5 + 7 &lt; 10"></row>
```

Using DOM:

```java
// Load XML from file
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = domBuilder.parse(file);

// Modify DOM tree (simple version)
NodeList rowNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("row");
for (int i = 0; i < rowNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node rowNode = rowNodes.item(i);

    // Remove existing content (if any)
    while (rowNode.getFirstChild() != null)
        rowNode.removeChild(rowNode.getFirstChild());

    // Add text content
    rowNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("some value"));
}

// Save XML to file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document),
                      new StreamResult(file));
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification